# Почему у меня выдаёт ошибку E0042 несовместимые типы операндов ("char" и "char *")?

Tags: c++, строки, указатели

```
char *fillChar(char str[], char sym[], int length) {
    char *ptrStr = str;
    char *ptrSym = sym;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (*(ptrStr + i) == ptrSym) {
            str[i] = str[i + 1];
        }
    }
    return ptrStr;
}
```

Почему у меня выдаёт ошибку в данной функции?

> Ошибка (активно)  E0042   несовместимые типы операндов ("char" и "char
>   *")

Comment: `*(ptrStr+i) == ptrSym` - что здесь с чем сравнивается?

Comment: На будущее, приводите текст ошибки *дословно*. Вы этим сэкономите нам время и увеличите свои шансы получить ответ.

Comment: Указатель на строку(получается символ) сравнивается с символом

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*(ptrStr+i) == ptrSym` - что здесь с чем сравнивается?

Значение `char` с указателем. Думаю, это неправильно.

---

```
char *removeSym(char str[], char sym, int length) {
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == sym) {
      for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
        str[j - 1] = str[j];
      }
      str[length - 1] = '\0';
      length--;
      i--;
    }
  }

  return str;
}
```

Comment: А как это правильно сделать?

Comment: @DenisShestopalov Что "это"? Смысл кода в функции `fillChar` от меня ускользает ).

Comment: Вообще надо написать  программу "Из предложения удалить все символы, совпадающие с символом, введенным с клавиатуры.", используя указатель как формальный параметр и результат выполнения функции